# Import real world map created with SLAM to CARLA

Tags: mapping, slam, carla, roadrunner

According to the CARLA doc.(https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.15/tuto_M_add_map_alternative/). You can add real-world maps using roadrunner or manually. CARLA primarily supports importing maps using OpenDrive or manually creating them with the OpenDRIVE format. The process involves defining roads, lanes, and other relevant information using XML files. The roadrunner tool mentioned in the documentation is designed for this purpose. However, I would like to know weather it is possible to import a map generated with SLAM using lidar to CARLA?